# Get similar key from object

Tags: javascript

I have created below function which checks for key in object & return value but i need the key itself, what fix need to be applied for this ?

```
function matchKey(objectToSearch, keyToFind) {
    for (var k in objectToSearch) {
        if ( k.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyToFind.toLowerCase()) !== -1) 
            return objectToSearch[k];
    }
    return null;
}

matchKey({year : 2015, "Price/STK" : "value"}, "price"); // returns "value"

desired output = "Price/STK"
```

Comment: If I've understood you right, it's as simple as just putting `return k` instead of `return objectToSearch[k]`

Comment: Please provide the desired output of the function.

Comment: what if object has multiple similar keys ?

Comment: You can use [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) instead of `indexOf() !== -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just return `k` instead of `objectToSearch[k]`:

```js
function matchKey(objectToSearch, keyToFind) {
    for (var k in objectToSearch) {
        if ( k.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyToFind.toLowerCase()) !== -1) 
            return k;
    }
    return null;
}

const result = matchKey({year : 2015, "Price/STK" : "value"}, "price"); // returns "Price/STK"

console.log(result);
```

Shortest implementation:

```js
const matchKey = (objectToSearch, keyToFind) =>
  Object.keys(objectToSearch).find(
    (k) => k.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyToFind.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  );

const result = matchKey({ year: 2015, "Price/STK": "value" }, "price"); // returns "Price/STK"

console.log(result);
```

If the object has multiple similar keys and you want the array of matching keys:

```js
const matchKey = (objectToSearch, keyToFind) =>
  Object.keys(objectToSearch).filter(
    (k) => k.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyToFind.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  );

const result = matchKey({ year: 2015, "Price/STK": "value", "sdfsdfpricedsg": "value" }, "price");
// returns "Price/STK"

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if object has multiple similar keys ?

Comment: It returns one key only, if multiple similar keys are there.